# How to show Rademacher functions are independent.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, borel-sets

Rademacher functions are defined on [0,1] in the following way. Let $x= 0.d_1 d_2 d_3...$ , the binary expansion of x in [0,1], where the expansion is non terminating (so 1= 0.111111111.... and not 1). Then the kth radamacher functions is defined as  $R_k(x)= -1$ if $d_k=0$ and $R_k(x)=1$ if $d_k=1$. The measure used is borel measure on [0,1]. We say $f$ and $g$ are independent if $m(f^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B))= m(f^{-1}(A)) m(g^{-1}(B))$ for all borel sets A,B.

I have tried to show any two Rademacher functions are independent but have not succeeded. I thought of splitting the cases where each function equals 1 and -1 and so on but it gets more and more complicated. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Note that you only need to consider $A,B \in \{ \{+1\}, \{-1\}\}$.

Comment: I thought of that, but why? Since any Borel set can be constructed using open intervals and the only values the radamacher functions take are -1 and 1?

Comment: The Rademacher functions only take values $\pm 1$. So for any set $A$ (or $B$), it its only relevant if $1 \in A$ and/or $-1 \in A$. Note that if $f,g$ are Rademacher functions, then $m(f^{-1}(\{1\})) = {1 \over 2}$ and similarly for $g$ (and similarly for $-1$). If $\{-1,1\} \subset A$ (or $B$) there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $R_k$ only takes values $\pm 1$.

Note that for any $k$ and $v \in \{-1,1\}$ we have
$m\{x \in [0,1] | R_k(x) = v \} = {1 \over 2}$.

Suppose $k\neq l$ and $v_k,v_l \in \{-1,1\}$, then note that $m\{x \in [0,1] | R_k(x) = v_k, R_l(x)= v_l \} = {1 \over 4}$ (this is
the essence of the solution).

Since $R_k^{-1}(A) = R_k^{-1}(A \cap \{-1,1\})$,
you only need to consider $A$ of the form $\emptyset, \{-1\}, \{1\}, \{-1,1\}$, and similarly for $B$. The first and last of these are
straightforward, and the other cases can be addressed using the previous two remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof based binary expansion of numbers in the unit intervals and building a sequence of Bernoulli iid random variables.

---

As in the posting of the OP states,   every $x\in[0,1]$ has a unique binary expansion
$x=\sum_{n\geq1}d_n(x)/2^n$ where $d_n(x)\in\{0,1\}$, and
$\sum_{n\geq1}d_n(x)=\infty$ for $x>0$.
Notice that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the $n$--th bit map $x\mapsto d_n(x)$ defines a measurable function from
$([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]))$ to
$(\{0,1\},\mathscr{P}(\{0,1\}))$. Therefore, the map
$\beta:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ given by
$x\mapsto(d_n(x))$ is measurable. The next result is a mathematical
formulation of tossing a fair coin.

> Lemma A: Suppose $\theta\sim U[0,1]$, and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $X_n=d_n\circ\theta$.  Then,  $(X_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is an i.i.d.  Bernoulli
> sequence with rate $p=\tfrac12$.
> Conversely, if $(X_n)$ is an i.i.d.  Bernoulli sequence with rate
> $p=\tfrac12$,
> then $\theta=\sum_{n\geq1}2^{-n}X_n\sim U[0,1]$.

Here I present a proof of this Lemma. Suppose that $\theta\sim U(0,1)$. For any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$k_1,\ldots,k_N\in\{0,1\}$,
\begin{align}
\bigcap^N_{j=1}\{x\in(0,1]:d_j(x)=k_j\}&=(\sum^N_{j=1}\tfrac{k_j}{2^j},
\sum^N_{j=1}\tfrac{k_j}{2^j}+\tfrac{1}{2^N}]\\
\{x\in(0,1]:
   d_N(x)=0\}&=\bigcup^{2^{N-1}-1}_{j=0}(\tfrac{2j}{2^N},\tfrac{2j+1}{2^N}]\\
\{x\in(0,1]:d_N(x)=1\}&=\bigcup^{2^{N-1}-1}_{j=0}
(\tfrac{2j+1}{2^N},\tfrac{2(j+1)}{2^N}]
\end{align}
It follows immediately that
$
\mathbb{P}\big[\bigcap^N_{j=1}\{X_j=k_j\}\big]=\tfrac{1}{2^N}=\prod^N_{j=1}\mathbb{P}[X_j=k_j]$.
Hence  $\{X_n\}$ is a Bernoulli sequence with rate $\tfrac12$.

Conversely, suppose $\{X_n:n\geq1\}$ is a Bernoulli sequence with rate
$\tfrac12$. If $\widetilde{\theta}\sim U(0,1)$ then,  the first part
shows that the sequence of bits
$\{\widetilde{X}_n\}\stackrel{law}{=}\{X_n\}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\theta:=\sum_{n\geq1}2^{-n}X_n\stackrel{law}{=}
\sum_{n\geq1}2^{-n}\widetilde{X}_n=\widetilde{\theta}
\end{align}
since $\theta$ is a measurable function of $\{X_n\}$.
This concludes the proof of the Lemma.

---

To conclude, consider in particular the probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})=([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]),m)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure in the unit interval. The Lemma above shows that the bits $d_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ in the binary expansion of numbers in $[0,1]$ form an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli $0-1$ random variables with parameter $p=1/2$. Hence, the sequence
$$R_n(x)=2d_n(x)-1$$
forms an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli $\pm1$ random variables with parameter $1/2$.

---

**Observation:** For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $R_n(x)=\operatorname{sign}(\sin(2^n\pi x))$ a.s. This is typically how the Rademacher sequence is defined in many Probability and Analysis textbooks.