# $\phi: (X, \mu) \to (\Bbb T, m_{\Bbb T})$ given by $\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}$ is measure-preserving

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, borel-sets

> Let $X = \{0,1\}^\Bbb{N}$ with the product measure $\mu = \prod_{\Bbb N} \nu$, where $\nu(\{0\}) = \nu(\{1\}) = \frac12$. The map $\sigma:X\to X$ by $\sigma(x_0, x_1, \ldots) = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ is the left-shift operator on $X$. It is easy to see that $\sigma$ preserves $\mu$, i.e., for every measurable subset $B \in \mathscr B$ of the measure space $(X,\mathscr B, \mu)$, we have $\mu(B) = \mu(\sigma^{-1}(B))$. Define a map $\phi:X\to \Bbb T$ by $$\phi(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}$$

I would like to show that $\phi$ is measure-preserving from $(X, \mu)$ to $(\Bbb T, m_{\Bbb T})$.

*Remark*. $\mu$ and $m_{\Bbb T}$ are probability measures, and $\Bbb T = \Bbb R/\Bbb Z \cong S^1$.

---

We need to show that $$\mu(\phi^{-1}(B)) = m_{\Bbb T} (B)$$ for all Borel-measurable subsets of $\Bbb T$. It is enough to prove the result for the generators of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb T$, i.e., the open sets in $\Bbb T$. What do open sets in $\Bbb T$ look like? I need to understand better $m_{\Bbb T}$ and open sets in $\Bbb T$ to tackle the problem. Thanks for any help! I'd appreciate a detailed explanation if possible.

---

**Reference:** *Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory* by Manfred Einsiedler and Thomas Ward.

Comment: It suffices to check the equality $\mu(\phi^{-1}(B)) = m(B)$ when $B$ is a dyadic interval.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Why is that? My fundamental question is about understanding exactly what the open sets in $\Bbb T$ are.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yes, please allow me some time.

Answer (score 2):

Call $p$ the canonical projection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. By definition of the quotient topology, the open sets in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are the subsets of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ whose premiages by $p$ are open sets on $\mathbb{R}$.

One can check that the open sets in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are the union of « open intervals » of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (namely images by $p$ of open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$). Any such union can be written as a countable union of « open intervals » simply by looking at the connected components.

Hence it suffices to look at « open intervals » of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Since any open interval can be written as a countable union of disjoint dyadic intervals, it suffices to look at dyadic intervals.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I can see that any open subset of $\Bbb R$ is a countable disjoint union of dyadic intervals, so if $U\subset\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is open, then $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R$. Therefore, $p^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} A_n$ where $\{A_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of disjoint dyadic intervals. Applying $p$ on both sides, $U = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} p(A_n)$. What's next?

Answer (score 1):

The projections $X_n(\omega)=\omega_n$ on $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, with the measure structure $(\Omega,(2^{\{0,1\}})^{\otimes\mathbb{N}},\mu)$, form an i.i.d sequence of standard Bernoulli random variables. The map $\phi:\omega\mapsto \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{-n}\omega_n$ induced the Lebesgue measure on $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]))$ (see for example the Lemma in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4434309/121671)), that is $$m=\mu\circ\phi^{-1}$$
which is basically what the OP is asking about (seem comments related to the dynamics on $\mathbb{R}\mod 1$ and the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$).

The shift operator $S$ on $\Omega$ translate into the map $T:x\mapsto\{2x\}$ on $[0,1]$ where $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor=x\mod1$, that is
$$\phi\circ S = T\circ \phi$$

Since $\mu$ and $m$ are $S$ and $T$ invariant respectively, the dynamical systems $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu,T)$ and $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]), m,T)$ are conjugate (some minor details about bijectively need to be addressed, see comments).

---

**Comments:**

- The map is 1-1 $\mu$-almust surely. For example, consider the set $R$ that admit a unique binary expansion. $Q=[0,1]\setminus R$ is countable and hence of Lebesgue measure $0$ and so,  and $S'=\phi^{-1}(Q)$ is also countable and hence also of $\mu$-measure $0$.
  The map $\phi:S'\rightarrow R$ is bijective $\sum_nr_n=\infty$ and let $S'=\phi^{-1}([0,1]\setminus R)$. As $Q=[0,1]\setminus R$ is countable, $S'$
- The unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ and the unit interval $[0,1)$ are measurable isometric: $f:\theta\mapsto e^{2\pi i\theta}$ is one such measurable isomorphism. If $\lambda$ is the arch length on $\mathbb{S}^1$, and $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)$ then $m\circ f^{-1}=\frac{1}{2\phi}\lambda$ and $\lambda\circ f=2\pi m$.
- arch length is invariant under the map $D:z\mapsto z^2$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$; moreover
  $$ D\circ f = f \circ T$$
  Thus, $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]),m,T)$ and $(\mathbb{S}^1,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{S}^1),\lambda/2\pi,D)$ are conjugate.

Comment: What's the arch length?

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic: it is literally the measure induced by the length of arches in a circle, for example, the arch-length of the unit circle is $2\pi$, half a circle is $\pi$, etc.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic: I noticed you unaccented my answer. Do you have some questions  about my solution?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution using the dyadic intervals approach, so I wanted to wait before accepting. Could you help out with it, by the way?

Comment: The solution to the first part contained in the [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4434309/121671) used dyadic intervals. It is much easier(due to basic knowledge of base expansion of numbers) to start with a uniform distribution and show that the sequence of bits in the binary expansion with infinitely many $1$'s form an i.i.d.  sequence of standard Bernoulli random variables (here one uses certain dyadic intervals). The uniqueness of the aw of the i.i.d sequence (a dynkin monotone class argument) takes care of the rest.